# Is React With TypeScript Still Worth While Now That React With Hooks Has Arrived?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

The team and I are embarking on a React project. We are primarily a Microsoft team who are all experienced with .Net for decades!

We have been really impressed with React and feel like we are going down that route. We have done all the Angular vs Vue vs other options to death.

As we are all C# developers we are planning to use React with TypeScript. Mainly for two reasons

1. We are used to a strongly typed code bases coming from C#, so we have been more successful with the React with TypeScript.
2. The code base has the potential to become quite large and we plan on sharing React components and TypeScript interfaces between teams/projects via an internal NPM registry. We think TypeScript will highlight typing issues early especially when refactoring and allow sharing more effectively.

I have talked with another similar sized team who did not start out with TypeScript (or Flow) they ran into refactoring problems when their solution got large and retrofitted in TypeScript.

I would like to start out with TypeScript from day one as a result

However, I am getting some push back from the more Javascript orientated developers. Who say:

1. TypeScript not required in modern ES6 JavaScript applications
2. The wider React community does not use TypeScript
3. Hooks which are new to React compound the points above

Have I wandered into a religious argument rather than a technical one (static typing vs dynamic) or are there points justified?

Happy to admit I am a JavaScript novice compared to my C# experience so I could be totally missing the point.

I thought I would pose the question to the community and find out some educated opinions. Please be kind

Comment: Complex business logic? Need maintainability? Use TS. Otherwise don't

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  

Oh yeah, all of that. Complexity is certainly a factor and quite a large team x code base so maintainability is also very important.

Comment: I personally just always use TS  to avoid decision fatigue and because in the end this always pays off.

Comment: That is a good point. Easier to add from the start, harder to add later so add it early.

Comment: Tell the people resisting TypeScript that they can either accept it, or find a new job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. TypeScript not required in modern ES6 JavaScript applications

It depends on what the requirements are. You say you anticipate refactoring, I have some experience with refactoring my own javascript and TypeScript projects. I can say that without TypeScript, refactoring takes more effort - you have to look at the implementation code a lot, just to be able to understand what the interface is. This can be alleviated by extensive amount of API documentation and unit tests, but - how many projects out there have those, and how many projects maintain the API doc so that it matches 100% with the actual code? Type annotations are a nice way to express what the expectations in the code are, and have a side benefit to be maintained together with the code.

> 2. The wider React community does not use TypeScript

Everyone uses what's best for their needs. In reality, there is no "community", there's just a bunch of people working on different projects. What's suitable for a majority of people might not be the best for you.

> 3. Hooks which are new to React compound the points above

The [recent version of typings for React does seem to support hooks](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/30057). The result of  google search for "react hooks with typescript" shows that a lot of people are using React hooks with TypeScript. I'm not aware of any specific problems, but if there are any, there's a chance they will be sorted out, eventually.